# EditText OnFocusChangeListener() doesn't hide cursor and view

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, onfocuschangelistener

I made an `EditText` `OnFocusChangeListener` that supposedly hides the cursor and another view when it's not in focus (i.e. clicking anywhere on the screen aside from the `EditText` will hide those items). Clicking on the `EditText` is the only time that will display them.

This is my OnFocusChangeListener for my `EditText` `pageTitle`:

```
pageTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if(b) {
            pageTitle.setCursorVisible(true);
            saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            pageTitle.setCursorVisible(false);
            saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

I also made an `OnclickListener`:

```
pageTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        pageTitle.setCursorVisible(true);
        saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

The OnClickListener works but not the OnFocusListener. Ideally, `pageTitle`'s cursor and `saveCancelBar` are initially hidden and will only appear when `pageTitle` is clicked.

This my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="missingPrefix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="app.wanderast.activity.AddPhotoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/arrow_left"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="36dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:maxLength="64"
            android:privateImeOptions="nm"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="4sp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey700"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@color/grey700"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:text="List View"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chevron_circle_down"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add_photo_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:minLines="0"
                    android:text="Add your first travel moment to your story"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/capture_photo_button"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/camera"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Capture Moment"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/add_photo_button"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/photo"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Add from Gallery"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_view_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="150dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--Navbar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photo_story_navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

            <!-- Take Photo Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_capture_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/green_pill_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/camera"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Capture"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Add from Gallery Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/photo"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Review button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_review_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/red_500_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Review"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/angle_double_right"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/save_cancel_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/black_border_top"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/save_title_btn"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="Save Title"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_title_btn"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_700_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#616161" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share the whole layout

Comment: @PunitSharma, i posted the whole layout

Comment: the setOnFocusChangeListener doesn't work?? I test your code and it works fine~~ can you show me how you define the `pageTitle` instance?

Comment: @Teocci, for some reason, it worked when I reversed the if condition from `b` to `!b`.

Comment: @Bargain23 ahh I was near to add my solution that is your error I put it on the solutions ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the definition of [`onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) you will notice that your code must change like this:

```
pageTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            pageTitle.setCursorVisible(true);
            saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            pageTitle.setCursorVisible(false);
            saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code for checking the soft keyboard visibility in Android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView saveCancelBar;
    private EditText pageTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setListenerToRootView();

        saveCancelBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cancel_bar);
        pageTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);

        pageTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                ...
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListenerToRootView()
    {
        final View activityRootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int screenHeight = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight();

                // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
                // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
                int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

                Log.e(TAG, "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

                if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                    // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gotcha!!! softKeyboard open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // keyboard is closed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gotcha!!! softKeyboard closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unrelated, but would you happen to know of a way to hide `saveCancelBar` when the soft keyboard is hidden?

Comment: @Bargain23 do you want to hide the saveCancelBar when the soft keyboard is hidden?

Comment: Yeah, is that possible?

Comment: @Bargain23  Yeah, sure it is. you have tow options: One is to check when the `LinearLayout` is resized by the soft keyboard or listening to the root view of your `Activity`. The first option needs a new class that extends the `LinearLayout`. The second one I will implement it here as part of my answerd

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about `activityRootView`. Thank you for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `focusableInTouchMode`. Add `focusableInTouchMode` to your `editText` to get focused on touching the view.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I did that, but it still remains the same.